# Update JSON object using path and value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a csv file that contains paths and values in the following format:

```
path;value
prop1.prop2.1;hello
prop1.prop2.2;world
prop1.prop2.3;!
prop1.prop3.test;hi
prop1.prop4;value
```

And I wand to get it as json:

```
{
  "prop1": {
    "prop2": {
      "1": "hello",
      "2": "world",
      "3": "!"
    }
    "prop3": {
      "test": "hi"
    }
    "prop4": "value"
  }    
}
```

I've parsed csv file like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
while (csv.Read())
{
  string path = csv.GetField<string>(0);
  string value = csv.GetField<string>(1);
  dict.Add(path, value);
}
```

Could you help me with method, that will create JSON from this dictionary using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Library.
Of course properties in original file can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to get the Json back as a string from your Dictionary

```
public static string BuildJson(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict.Where(x => !string.Equals(x.Key, "path")))
    {
        string[] pathArray = pair.Key.Split('.');
        var currentExpando = expando as IDictionary<string, Object>;

        for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == pathArray.Count() - 1)
            {
                currentExpando.Add(pathArray[i], pair.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!currentExpando.Keys.Contains(pathArray[i]))
                {
                    currentExpando.Add(pathArray[i], new ExpandoObject());
                }
                currentExpando = currentExpando[pathArray[i]] as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            }
        }
    }

    JObject o = JObject.FromObject(expando);
    return o.ToString();
}
```

you need to add a using System.Dynamic;

Comment: It works great, but it fails when you have one property like: prop1.prop2.prop2

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public string ToJson(Dictionary<string, string> props)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> json = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        string path = prop.Key;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) continue;
        string[] keys = path.Split('.');

        string value = prop.Value;

        var cursor = json;

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            object innerJson;
            if (!cursor.TryGetValue(keys[i], out innerJson))
                cursor.Add(keys[i], new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>);
            if (i == keys.Length - 1)
                cursor[keys[i]] = value;

            cursor = cursor[keys[i]] as IDictionary<string, object>;
        }

    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using dynamic:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
while (csv.Read())
{
  string path = csv.GetField<string>(0);
  string value = csv.GetField<string>(1);
  dictionary = GetHierarchy(path, value);
}
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
```

Add following method:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetHierarchy(Dictionary<string, object> root, string path, string value)
{
    string[] parts = path.Split('.');
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        if(!root.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
            root.Add(parts[0], new Dictionary<string, object>());
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = root[parts[0]] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        GetMe(dict, path.Replace(parts[0] + ".", string.Empty), value);
    }
    else 
        root[parts[0]] = value;
    return root;
}
```

Generates the expected output