# How to create JSON object from JSON node path in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, json-path-expression

I want to map JSON path properties from key-value pairs to generate the JSON object in **C#** where the path contains nested array index path

Input:

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
properties.put("id", "1");
properties.put("name", "sample_name");
properties.put("category.id", "1");
properties.put("category.name", "sample");
properties.put("tags[0].id", "1");
properties.put("tags[0].name", "tag1");
properties.put("tags[1].id", "2");
properties.put("tags[1].name", "tag2");
properties.put("status", "available");
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "sample_name",
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sample"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "tag1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "tag2"
    }
  ],
 
  "status": "available"
}
```

Using [Jackson's JavaPropsMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/139) it can easily be achieved like:

```
JavaPropsMapper javaPropsMapper = new JavaPropsMapper();
JsonNode json = javaPropsMapper.readMapAs(properties, JsonNode.class);
```

How to implement this idea in **C#** so that I am able to generate the JSON object from the given JSON path node.

Comment: Which JSON serialiser are you using?

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft JSON serializer

Comment: Similar question here: [Update JSON object using path and value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36056893/10263)

Answer (score 1):

you can create anonymous object an serialize

```
            var values = new { 
                id = "id",
                name = "name",
                category = new { id = 1, name = "sample"},
                tags = new { id = 0, name = "sample" },
                status = "available"
            }; 
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

Comment: First of all how would I parse the given expression in my dictionary such as tags[0].id. I have this input dynamic in nature. I can get any kind of expression out of which I need to generate the JSON node